# PHP SOAP Error through Proxy

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

i keep getting an stupid error in PHP related to `SOAP` which i can't solve. I've searched quite much via Google and in the official manual, but there is nothing helpful for me.

This is my problem: I got an official endpoint adress: `$wsdl = example.com/wsdl`, which i need to use for an soap request. The problem is that there is an proxy at my university trying to destroy all my work. So in general i need to get past my proxy, then access the wsdl file successfully and then authenticate at the web service.

What i have tried:

```
$wsdl = "example.com/wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,array('user' => 'username','password' => 'password'));
```

This throws the error:

```
"SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from ... : failed to load external entity"
```

I also tried to cache the external wsdl file via file_get_contents by creating an valid stream with `stream_context_create()` which also resulted in the same error message.

How can i access this thing now? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check the options parameter for [`SoapClient`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php).

Comment: Yes i've looked at the SoapClient options very often and yes i saw proxy_host and proxy_login as parameters etc., but they don't work in my example!